# Spring Boot RabbitMQ with AMQP Library or RabbitMQ Library

Tags: spring, spring-boot, rabbitmq, spring-amqp

I started working with messaging queues using RabbitMQ, I am fine with using AMQP below is the code, so I discovered that when going with RabbitTemplate and amqp.connectionFactory, we cannot have have Channel Bean from the same org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.connection.ConnectionFactory.

but I want to use the Channel object to set manual ACK using basiAck,

```
@RabbitListener(queues = "email_queue", concurrency = "4", ackMode = "Manual")
    @Retryable(value = {Exception.class}, maxAttempts = 3, backoff = @Backoff(1000))
    public void sendEmail(String customerEmail, Channel channel,  @Header(AmqpHeaders.DELIVERY_TAG) long deliveryTag) throws IOException {
        try {
            SimpleMailMessage simpleMailMessage = new SimpleMailMessage();
            simpleMailMessage.setFrom("kartikpawade25@gmail.com");
            simpleMailMessage.setTo(customerEmail);
            simpleMailMessage.setText("Hi, your ticket has been booked Successfully.");
            simpleMailMessage.setSubject("Movie Tickets Booked");
            javaMailSender.send(simpleMailMessage);

            channel.basicAck(deliveryTag, false);
        }catch (Exception e){
            log.error("Email Consumer Service::" + e.getMessage());
            throw e;
        }
    }
```

The problem is,  I have not defined Channel Object/Bean in rabbit-config, How will I be getting it from rabbitTemplate, so I can pass it as parameter in above method. below is my RabbitConfig.

```
@Configuration
public class RabbitConfig {
    @Value("${rabbitmq.email.queue}")
    private String emailQueueName;
    @Value("${rabbitmq.email.exchange.name}")
    private String emailExchangeName;
    @Value("${rabbitmq.email.binding.key}")
    private String emailBindingKey;

    @Bean
    public Queue emailQueue() {
        return new Queue(emailQueueName);
    }

    @Bean
    public TopicExchange topicExchange() {
        return new TopicExchange(emailExchangeName);
    }

    @Bean
    public Binding binding() {
        return BindingBuilder.bind(emailQueue()).to(topicExchange()).with(emailBindingKey);
    }

    @Bean
    public AmqpTemplate amqpTemplate(ConnectionFactory connectionFactory) {
        RabbitTemplate rabbitTemplate = new RabbitTemplate();
        rabbitTemplate.setConnectionFactory(connectionFactory);
        rabbitTemplate.setMessageConverter(messageConverter());
        return rabbitTemplate;
    }

    @Bean
    public MessageConverter messageConverter() {
        return new Jackson2JsonMessageConverter();
    }
}
```

should I use the rabbitmq.client library to define connectionFactory -> new connection -> channel -> build queues....
and then use the Channel as @Autowired property?
Do I need to switch from amqp library to rabbitMq library fully?

Any complete code/github example is much appritiated,Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No you do not need to do that.

The `@RabbitListener` is not a bean, but rather a handler method which is called by the framework when message has arrived to the listener container.

The arguments for those params in the method signature are set by the `MessagingMessageListenerAdapter`:

```
return this.handlerAdapter.invoke(message, amqpMessage, channel, amqpMessage.getMessageProperties());
```

That adapter does other smart job trying to resolve some other arguments if you use `@Header` as you do in your case.

See more info in docs: https://docs.spring.io/spring-amqp/reference/amqp/receiving-messages/async-annotation-driven.html

Comment: This was whole set of new info I got to know, thanks a lot. I could not find this anywhere easily, So I had to post a question here.

Comment: Just for reference, I am adding exact referenceDocs and quote below.
[https://docs.spring.io/amqp/inbound-ack.html](https://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/reference/amqp/inbound-ack.html)

"Setting the mode to MANUAL lets user code acknowledge the message at some other point during processing. To support this, with this mode, the endpoints provide the Channel and deliveryTag in the amqp_channel and amqp_deliveryTag headers, respectively."